# Set the angle of a sprite in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

How would I set the angle of a sprite to 45 degrees?

```
SKAction *rotate = [SKAction rotateByAngle: M_PI/4.0 duration:1];
```

only increases the angle by 45 degrees, what I want to do is have to `SKSprite` rotate however long it takes to get to 45 and then stop. Is there a method for that or will I have to hard code it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The method you’re looking for is `+rotateToAngle:duration:shortestUnitArc:`, as in:

```
SKAction *rotate = [SKAction rotateToAngle:M_PI_4 duration:1 shortestUnitArc:YES];
```

You can also just use `+rotateToAngle:duration:`, but that always rotates counterclockwise; this variant goes in whichever direction requires the least rotation.

(also note that π/4 is already defined as a constant, `M_PI_4`; see usr/include/math.h)